# What is this 10 pin connector?

Tags: identification, connector, plug, socket

I'm trying to identify the 10 pin connector in the image below. Pin pitch is either 0.8 or 0.9mm (no calipers available). The outer plastic housing is 6mm x 4mm.

Any ideas?

[image: 10 pin connector]

Comment: it's a type of a mezzanine connector

Comment: Well this isn't "calipers online", post the question when you have measured the pitch... Hirose have lots of connectors like this. Since SOT23-5 has around 1mm pitch I doubt these are 0.8mm.

Comment: @Lundin Pitch is 0.8 or 0.9mm. I can't get any more accurate than that. Dimensions and pitch is at the start of the question, above the image

Comment: If your measurement of the outer dimensions are correct, the pitch would be 0.8mm (yes, I measured it :) Pretty easy based on your photo )

Answer (score 0):

It's a [C-T genderless board-to-board connectors](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=c_t_b2b_conn) (my site).

0.8 mm pitch connectors are listed, but none of them look quite like yours. The closest one is the  [Molex SlimStack 0.8mm](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=c_t_b2b_conn_0p8&s=SlimStack%200.8mm%20TC), but the housing is shaped a bit differently. It looks more like a [Panasonic P5KS](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=c_t_b2b_conn_0p5&s=P5KS), but its pitch is 0.5 mm.